# About an UnsastifiedLinkException with opencv and java on osx

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to create the typical first project on this technology, I have followed the steps from this [link](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/02-first-java-application-with-opencv.html). I installed java version using brew, I can see jar file and dylib file in folder:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.2/share/OpenCV/java/
$ pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.2/share/OpenCV/java
$ ls
libopencv_java342.dylib opencv-342.jar
```

then i copy the jar file to another accesible folder and i create the User variable with that folder.

I add this variable to the project

[image]

But i am getting this exception, I notice that is complaining about a version of a library I'm not providing in the user variable. It says version 2.4.8 when brew installs version 3.4.2.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java248 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at HelloCV.main(HelloCV.java:7)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the dll. Try adding it to your project path.

Comment: I have two files, libopencv_java342.dylib and opencv-342.jar.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java248 in java.library.path` - you are managing different versions and should organize your imports. Your main is expecting an OpenCV version 2.48, you are providing version 3.42. Version 3 to 2 is not downwards compatible since they did some major changes in the package organization.

Comment: Did you use a different version in your project at any point?

Comment: hum, i think so. I started to play with this "hello world" project some days ago. I will start from scratch in a new workspace. Thank you @T A